# Does anyone say not to make noise for Haman?

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, purim, megillat-esther, haman

[Here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36363/source-to-make-noise-when-hamans-name-is-mentioned) is the source that you should make noise at the mention of Haman's name.

However, as I was listening to the Megillah this year it occurred to me how counterproductive it is as an act of erasing Amalek, as this ends up requiring the reader to repeat Haman's name so that everyone will hear it.  So it amounts to increasing the mention of Amalek.

Are there any sources that say specifically *not* to make noise for Haman's name, for this reason?

Comment: Yes Rav Henkin held if it is disruptive it would not be done

Comment: @sam Thank you.  I finished with the words "for this reason" to rule out that reason.

Comment: The idea of wiping out the name of amelek also has to do with the remembrance of amelek,you can't have one without the other one,it is not a stirah to hear hamans name again because it is another opportunity to remember what amelek did.

Comment: @sam well you aren't doing very much wiping out of the latter mention.  I don't think we go around putting up Amalek reminders and not destroying them so there will be more Amalek remembrance.

Comment: I am just addressing you statement of being counterproductive,we bang to wipe out the name but there is a technical problem of hearing every letter so they repeat the word in order to fulfill the mitzvah,I don't see an issue with it.

Comment: Maaseh Rav. In our shul at Shacharis, the Rav said that since the noisemaking was lemhadrin min hamehadrin min hamehadrin min hamehadrin in the night, we should only bang for the first and last mentions of Hxoxmxoxn's name.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Ezras Torah](http://www.ezrastorah.org/index.php) [Luach](http://www.ezrastorah.org/choose_content.php?action=calendar), 5774 Edition, pp. 101-102:

> Rav Henkin noted that the Reading of
>   the Megillah, both at night as well as in the
>   morning, is an obligation incumbent upon
>   every man and woman. Therefore, the reader
>   must have a powerful voice that can be heard
>   by everyone. He must read very precisely,
>   without swallowing any words or even
>   letters. For if anyone misses hearing even
>   one word, he does not fulfill his obligation.
>   Because of the noise that is made after the
>   mention of Haman, many people do not
>   hear the words, and thus fail to perform a
>   Biblical ( מדברי קבלה ) commandment. Those
>   who initiated this custom of making noise at
>   the mention of Haman's name, had the pure
>   intentions of performing the Mitzvah in a
>   superior fashion. But, today the interest is
>   only in wanton levity and unruly conduct
>   that is always prohibited. The Sefardim have
>   a custom of making noise only at the mention
>   of Haman during the singing of Shoshanas
>   Yaakov, after the Reading of the Megillah
>   is already over. This is a fitting custom that
>   should be universally adopted. However,
>   during the reading of the Megillah, we
>   should tolerate no noise-making.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question, which sought, very specifically, a source for not banging because doing so would cause the reader to repeat the name and that'd be increasing the mention of _Amalek_, precisely the opposite of what is intended by the banging.

Comment: Fair enough. [15]

Comment: Sefaradim say Shoshanas Yaakov?

Answer (score 1):

The Chabad custom is to stomp feet instead of making noise with one's voice and/or noisemakers. In my experience, this makes it easier to hear the recitation. I'm not sure if that is the reason for the custom, or where the custom originates.